# Alpha nvim not starting

Tags: neovim

It has something to do with my configuration, but I can't seem to display [Alpha](https://github.com/goolord/alpha-nvim) when starting nvim.
There isn't even `:Alpha` when I start nvim, I have to type `:lua require'alpha'.setup(require'alpha.themes.startify'.config)`, to be able to launch it.

This leads me to believe that I messed up somewhere in my config.
If you could please take a look to help me, [here](https://github.com/enrico223/.config/tree/main/nvim) is my config.

I only have this in my `packer.lua` for `alpha` in my config.

```
--Plug for greet screen
use {
    'goolord/alpha-nvim',
    requires = { 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons' },
    config = function ()
        require'alpha'.setup(require'alpha.themes.startify'.config)
    end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing `require'alpha'.setup(require'alpha.themes.startify'.config)` in my `init.lua` fixed the problem.